# Python regular expression how to ignore search from start of string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Input :- "INeedSomeHelpWithARegex"

Expected Output :- "I_Need_Some_Help_With_A_Regex"

What I tried

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'([A-Z])([a-z]*)',r'_\1\2',"INeedSomeHelpWithARegex"))
```

Actual Output got :- "_I_Need_Some_Help_With_A_Regex"

How can we avoid "_" at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds to pick the place to insert an underscore; a lookbehind for a letter, and a lookahead for a capital letter:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])', '_', "INeedSomeHelpWithARegex"))
```

Output:

```
I_Need_Some_Help_With_A_Regex
```

Comment: Can't we use `\B(?=[A-Z])`?

Comment: @Slkrasnodar, it depends on what the OP wants, which we've not been told. If the string were `"I1NeedSomeHelp"` use of your regex would result in `"I1_Need_Some_Help"`, whereas use of Nick's would return `"I1Need_Some_Help`. I am so weary of questions being asked in terms of a single example, as opposed to providing a complete and precise statement of the problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland indeed. Unfortunately you can only answer what has been asked...

Comment: @sakeesh Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?